# Search for identical strings of certain length in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question concerning a large dataset containing a column 'text' with strings. My goal is to search for identical strings with a minimum of 20 characters in Python. The dataset that I need thus contains al these identical strings.

For example the following dataset named df:

```
  idnr       text 

      1      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
      2      Shorter sentence
      3      Short
      4      Short
      5      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
      6      Shorter sentence
      7      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
      8      Shorter sentence
      9      Short
     10      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
     11      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
     12      Shorter sentence
```

The output should be:

```
  idnr       text 

      1      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
      5      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
      7      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
     10      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
     11      This sentence is more than 20 characters long
```

What script can I use for this in Python?

Comment: what if the dataframe contains 2 or more different string which lengths are greater than 20?

Comment: Is there only one string that has length >= 20? If so, why not simply filter by length?

Comment: It contains a large dataset with several different pieces of text. I want to search for identical text. Sometimes the text has a length of 40 characters, sometimes of 25 etc. The script needs to return all these sets of identical text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter rows by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with greater like `20` chained by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for 2 or more values:

```
df1 = df[df['text'].str.len().gt(20) & df['text'].duplicated(keep=False)]

print (df1)
    idnr                                           text
0      1  This sentence is more than 20 characters long
4      5  This sentence is more than 20 characters long
6      7  This sentence is more than 20 characters long
9     10  This sentence is more than 20 characters long
10    11  This sentence is more than 20 characters long
```

For testing is possible use:

```
m1 = df['text'].str.len().gt(20)
m2 = df['text'].duplicated(keep=False)
m3  = df['text'].str.len().gt(20) & df['text'].duplicated(keep=False)

print (df.assign(m1=m1, m2=m2, both=m3))
    idnr                                           text     m1    m2   both
0      1  This sentence is more than 20 characters long   True  True   True
1      2                               Shorter sentence  False  True  False
2      3                                          Short  False  True  False
3      4                                          Short  False  True  False
4      5  This sentence is more than 20 characters long   True  True   True
5      6                               Shorter sentence  False  True  False
6      7  This sentence is more than 20 characters long   True  True   True
7      8                               Shorter sentence  False  True  False
8      9                                          Short  False  True  False
9     10  This sentence is more than 20 characters long   True  True   True
10    11  This sentence is more than 20 characters long   True  True   True
11    12                               Shorter sentence  False  True  False
```

Comment: This script returns everything, not only duplicate strings of 20 or more. I only want to find identical strings of certain lenght. The text should be exactly the same.

Comment: @marita - Interesting, for me working very well.

Comment: @marita - `This script returns everything` - Can you be more specific? You need looking by parts of `text`, so need something else like my solution?